# Do I need to re-authenticate with Firebase if I call goOffline

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if I need to re-authenticate with Firebase if I call `firebase.database().goOffline` and then call `firebase.database().goOnline()` at a later time. It is not clear in the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goonline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online status of Realtime Database is not related to the state of the user's authentication.  Authentication state is handled automatically by Firebase Authentication.  The token that identifies the user is automatically refreshed every hour by the SDK, and you don't have to write any code to manage that.  It doesn't pay attention to whether or not the Realtime Database thinks it's online or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and elaborate response.